# Google maps-places api can't find a type: fishing ponds

Tags: google-places-api

I am using Places API and I want to find nearby fishing ponds in my Android project. Although fishing pond is a category in Google Maps it seems that it is not a type in the Places API. Is there someway I can get them?

Comment: The API has [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/supported_types).

Comment: Luca, "software recommendations" are considered off topic on this site. As such I have removed where you asked for one to make it more objective. (In my opinion I didn't think it was a big deal but I still removed it in case others feel differently and want to close the question due to it.)